# Interchanging the order of infinite and finite sum

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have the following series
$$f\left( {k,t} \right) = \sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {{a_n}(k){t^n}}.$$
It is obvious that 
$$\sum\limits_{k = 0}^m {f\left( {k,t} \right)}  = \sum\limits_{k = 0}^m {\sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {{a_n}(k){t^n}} }.$$
But I don't know if the following is true or not 
$$\sum\limits_{k = 0}^m {\sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {{a_n}(k){t^n}} }  = \sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {\sum\limits_{k = 0}^m {{a_n}(k){t^n}} }$$
I will appreciate if someone tell me under what conditions I can change the order of this double series.

Comment: I think absolute convergence is sufficient, but maybe this condition can be relaxed.

Comment: You can use Fubini's theorem with counting measures

Comment: Well it is not in general true, but if you know the double sum is finite, you can use Fubini's theorem with the counting measure to obtain your claim (well it works almost everywhere, but I guess that's fine). If you want it to work everywhere, you probably need absolute convergence.

Answer (score 0):

That is not always true.

Take $t=1$, $m=1$, $a_n(0)= (-1)^n$ and $a_n(1)=(-1)^{n+1}$. The equality 
$$\sum\limits_{k = 0}^m {\sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {{a_n}(k){t^n}} }  = \sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {\sum\limits_{k = 0}^m {{a_n}(k){t^n}} }$$ is not satisfied as $\sum (-1)^n$ doesn't converge.

Comment: thank you. But in my case the infinite series equals a known  two variable function, and I want to change the order of infinite series with finite. actually I want to know under what conditions I am allowed to do this.